# SKMaps crashing when it can't find a system file

Tags: java, android, skmaps

When I begin an activity using SKMaps I get this error:

```
06-23 01:18:28.241 3201-3201/? I/art:     Thread[1,tid=3201,Native,Thread*=0xb4134500,peer=0x74ad9f68,"main"] recursive     attempt to load library "/data/app/hci.wisc-2/lib/x86/libngnative.so"
06-23 01:18:28.242 3201-3201/? W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-23 01:18:28.242 3201-3201/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
06-23 01:18:28.242 3201-3201/? W/System.err:     at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:117)
06-23 01:18:28.243 3201-3201/? W/System.err:     at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:149)
06-23 01:18:28.243 3201-3201/? W/System.err:     at com.skobbler.ngx.util.SKUtils.a(SourceFile:123)
06-23 01:18:28.243 3201-3201/? W/System.err:     at com.skobbler.ngx.util.SKUtils.getStyleDetailForDevice(SourceFile:91)
06-23 01:18:28.243 3201-3201/? W/System.err:     at com.skobbler.ngx.SKMaps.initializeSKMaps(SourceFile:322)
06-23 01:18:28.243 3201-3201/? W/System.err:     at hci.wisc.Navigation.onCreate(Navigation.java:64)
```

And the relevant portions of Navigation.java

```java
    prepThread = new SKPrepareMapTextureThread(this, filePath, "SKMaps.zip",this );
    prepThread.run();
    mapViewStyle = new SKMapViewStyle(filePath+"/SKMaps/daystyle","daystyle.json");
    initMapSettings.setMapResourcesPath(filePath+"/SKMaps");
    advisorSettings.setLanguage(SKAdvisorSettings.SKAdvisorLanguage.LANGUAGE_EN_US);
    advisorSettings.setAdvisorType(SKAdvisorSettings.SKAdvisorType.TEXT_TO_SPEECH);
    advisorSettings.setAdvisorConfigPath(filePath+"/SKmaps/Languages/en_us/advisor_configfiles");
    initMapSettings.setAdvisorSettings(advisorSettings);
    initMapSettings.setMapsPath(filePath+"/SKMaps/PreinstalledMaps.v1");
    initMapSettings.setCurrentMapViewStyle(mapViewStyle);
    SKMaps.getInstance().setApiKey("8dfbd9888536061be77d892f929c61187e6951258ba359b53e1a7103cedd1395");
    SKMaps.getInstance().initializeSKMaps(this, initMapSettings);
```

Comment: The path set seems to be incorrect - check that